# ldap client container works with docker run but not on docker-compose or docker-stack

Tags: docker-compose, ldap, docker-stack

**Case 1 : Classic docker run**

With `env-file` :

```
BASE_DN=dc=example,dc=com
URI=ldap://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:389
ROOT_ADDCOUNT=cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Run the docker with :

```
docker run --env-file ./env-file -it -d akhilrajmailbox/ldap-client:latest /bin/bash
```

Get into the docker with

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

*==> Works, I can then reach my ldap*

**Case 2 : With docker-compose**

With `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "3"

services:
  ldap_client:
    restart: always
    image: akhilrajmailbox/ldap-client:latest
    environment:
      - 'BASE_DN="dc=example,dc=com"'
      - 'URI="ldap://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:389"'
      - 'ROOT_ADDCOUNT="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"'
      - 'ROOT_PASSWORD="mypassword"'
```

Run the docker-compose with :

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Get into the docker with

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

*==> Doesn't work, I cannot then reach my ldap*

**Case 3 : With docker-stack**

With same `docker-compose.yml` as above.

Run the docker-stack with :

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml my_stack
```

Get into the container as above

*==> Doesn't work, I cannot then reach my ldap*

**hints :**

- On both containers coming from `compose` & `stack` I get my environment variables.
- This looks like I can't reach `ldap://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:389` from them.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the issue with docker version 2, and the problem is in your "environment: " block. try to use the following format (avoid : " )
Example :: use `'BASE_DN=dc=example,dc=com'` instead of `'BASE_DN="dc=example,dc=com"'`

```
version: "2"

services:
  ldap_client:
    restart: always
    image: akhilrajmailbox/ldap-client:latest
    environment:
      - 'BASE_DN=dc=example,dc=com'
      - 'URI=ldap://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:389'
      - 'ROOT_ADDCOUNT=cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com'
      - 'ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword'
```

Note :: I tried with docker version 2 in yaml file.